# How to pass user input from ASP.NET TextBox to JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pull the information that the user inputs in the text boxes and pass the value to a JavaScript function in order to display the result in a "window.alert()" method.

I am currently using ASP.NET. This what I have so far for the ASP.NET front part and for the JavaScript;

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCalculateSalary" runat="server" Text="Calculate Salary" OnClick="calcFunction()" />

    <script>
        function calcFunction(c1, c2) {
            c1 = document.getElementById('txtAnnualHours').value;
            c2 = document.getElementById('txtPayRate').value;

            return window.alert("Your Annual Salary is: " + c1 * c2);
        }
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `OnClientClick` for your control, instead of `OnClick`?

Comment: Whichever one works. I am learning, so I don't know which one works accordingly with JavaScript.

Comment: Well, `OnClick` for server-side controls is to handle the server-side events.  Use `OnClientClick` for a client-side click handler.  Note however that it is still a server-side control and may still cause a post-back refreshing the whole page.

Comment: @David, so what would I need to do in order to let the button know that I want to take the information that the user inputted and pass it to the function in order to display it?

Comment: Let's say I am using 'OnClientClick' instead.

Comment: Well, what happens when you *try* `OnClick="calcFunction()"`?  Also, your JavaScript function doesn't seem to need those `c1, c2` parameters.  You don't pass it any values for them, nor do you use any passed values in the function.

Comment: Are your text boxes ASP.NET controls, or simple HTML? If they are ASP.NET controls, then  your calls to `getElementById` will not work, because the ID you give in the controls is *not* the actual client side ID.  To get around this, see http://www.jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

Comment: @David, it tells me that it does not contain a definition for "calcFunction()" when using "OnClick" function. I also deleted the parameters from the script section.

Comment: @JoelLee, they are supposed to be ASP.NET controls; and thanks, I will read it now.

Comment: @CristianUPolanco: That's because `OnClick` looks for *server-side* code to execute, and you have no `calcFunction()` method in your *server-side* code.  What happens when you try `OnClientClick` instead?

Comment: @David, it worked by using "OnClientClick" instead of "OnClick." Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CristianUPolanco:  Excellent.  Sorry for any confusion in there.  You'll find that the difference between server-side and client-side code will be *critically* important in web development in general.  ASP.NET WebForms goes to great length to try and unify these two separate things, often resulting in confusion and problems.  But I'm just exposing personal opinion at this point :)

Comment: @David, yes, I see that. I am a college student and I am new to all this, but no worries, it is all cleared up for me right now; I understand the concept.

Comment: @David, how do I give you guys a vote or a score? I am not too savvy about this website.

Comment: Here's a good article from Microsoft that makes it clear that there is a both a client side and a server side event, if you are using an ASP.NET button control.  I strongly recommend that you "view source" on your web form, in the browser, and look at what the ASP.NET control actually generates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CristianUPolanco: In this case only comments were given, not answers.  In the hopes of helping any future visitors, I'll post an answer below.  That can then be "upvoted" and "accepted" by you if you choose.

Comment: @David, sure. I want to give you guys some credit if possible.

Comment: Points will have to go to @David, since I am not posting an answer. :-) Just trying to help out because you are new. The best thing you can do for David is to both up vote his answer, and accept it as the correct answer. For future reference, make sure you actually *ask* a question in your post, or you are likely to get down voted.  Good luck.

Comment: @JoelLee, thanks a lot. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
OnClick="calcFunction()"
```

Since that's a server-side ASP.NET "control" and not an HTML element, `OnClick` is referring to ASP.NET's server-side event handlers.  But you have a client-side function to be executed.  In that case, try:

```
OnClientClick="calcFunction()"
```

One important thing to note, however, is that this is still a server-side ASP.NET control.  Which means that after processing the client-side click event it *may* (depending on a number of unrelated factors) still invoke a post-back to the server which will refresh the page.  A common source of confusion among beginners is that a quick page refresh will "reset" their client-side state and cause them to suspect that "it isn't working".

Often when all you want to do is perform client-side actions, you may want to skip the server-side controls altogether and just use normal HTML elements.

Another unrelated side note... Your JavaScript function doesn't need those `c1, c2` parameters in the function declaration.  Values aren't being passed to the function, and passed values aren't being used in the function.

Comment: really appreciate the additional comments.